# make new dataframes from grouped dataframe automatically

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe grouped

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 
    "Name" : ["Alice", "Bob", "Mallory", "Mallory", "Bob" , "Mallory"] , 
    "City" : ["Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland", "Seattle", "Seattle", "Portland"] } )



group = df1.groupby('City')

for city, city_df in group:
    print(city)

    print(city_df)
```

how can I get this output into new dataframes without specifying the new dfs ?
like if a got 4 groups out next time, i want to get 4 dfs automatically

```
Portland
      Name      City
2  Mallory  Portland
5  Mallory  Portland
Seattle
      Name     City
0    Alice  Seattle
1      Bob  Seattle
3  Mallory  Seattle
4      Bob  Seattle
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the magic method `__iter__()` to get a groupby iterator and convert it into a dictionary with `dict()`:

```
dct = dict(df.groupby('City').__iter__())
```

If you want to get separate dataframes from the dictionary you can use the method `values()`:

```
df1, df2 = dct.values()
```

Comment: how can I convert the dict autmatically into dfs without naming them?

Comment: @ErwinFeld I don't know. You can put dataframes into list. You can make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dictionary from the groupby object with:

```
d = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('City')))
```

---

```
print(d['Portland'])

    Name      City
2  Mallory  Portland
5  Mallory  Portland
```

Comment: can you show me how to get this dict into separtedd dfs ?                                           ` d = dict(tuple(df1.groupby('City'))) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)  `                                                                                     
  this gives me an error

Comment: You cannot have a dataframe of dataframes @ErwinFeld If you want multiple dataframes, and to be able to index them by some key, this is the way